# How does Expo work during and after building a package?

Tags: react-native, expo, google-play, apk, mobile-application

I'm a bit skeptical after doing a build apk on expo with a user account. The case is as follows: I must make two similar applications (A and B) for 2 companies, each one with characteristics specific to each company. When I have done "expo build apk" of the first application (A) in Expo, everything has gone well and I have been able to test the apk on a real device (not emulator). Then I build application B in expo with the same user account and everything ends well too, I have obtained an APK file. The problem I get is that when I opened app A on the real device, it was the interface of app B that started. It seemed that by using the same expo account to build, I had overwritten app B over app A. The only solution I did is to create another expo account to build the second app.

So I have two questions:

1. Can anyone tell me if my reasoning is correct? Does Expo only support one app per account?
2. When you upload the application (.APK or .AAB) to Google Play. Will the application still depend on Expo? I thought that Expo only build .apk and now it is independent file.

I really appreciate your comments and responses.